# How to display an image in colorbox larger than its original size?

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I have 500x500px images displayed in a colorbox popup (grouped by classname in  links), and I want to display them larger than their original size (90% of the screen size would be just perfect).

I could not find any solution to increase the size of the image, but only the size of the popup.
Even the $.colorbox.resize() method called after changing width and height of the loaded image doesn't seem to work.

The following code works if the image is bigger than 90% of the screen, but not if it's smaller.

```
$('.photos').colorbox({rel:'photos', maxHeight:'90%', maxWidth:'90%', scalePhotos:true});
```

If I add width:'90%',height:'90%', only the colorbox takes the right size, but the image keeps its original size (500x500px)

Is there any solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I was looking for something similar and ended up here.

The solution is to add to your script

```
$('.photos').colorbox({rel:'photos', width:'90%'});
```

and to your css

```
img.cboxPhoto { width:100% !importatnt; }
```

Try it through Firebug or other frontend inspecting tool.
I'm not fan of the `!important` tag but I don't know the other way to do it since colorBox adds styles directly to the element and not the class.